# Hosting xDB on same database server as content database (OnPrem)

Tags: xdb, xconnect

We are currently upgrading from `10.0 to 10.3 (on prem)`. Since `MongoDB` for the Experience Platform is no longer supported, we are attempting to set up our xDB on `SQL`. The SQL server that we currently have hosts our content database. Does anyone have experience hosting their `xDB` on the same server or should we spin up entirely separate servers for these? (as a side note, we get approximately 320k page requests/day)

Comment: I don’t see any issues hosting on same server unless your server is running out of resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if it's possible to host xDB databases on the same servers as the content database then the short answer is yes.

But then there are other things to consider like **scalability**. If you do not foresee any substantial increase in the xDB data (like adding new sites or getting new users in by adding more languages to existing websites) then you may go for setting up in the same server. But in the longer term, it might be beneficial to separate it out for scalability as well as troubleshooting purposes in case there are issues.
**Note:** Separate server means additional cost of License as well. Since your site is having a traffic of 320K page request/day, separate server is the correct way while upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to go with separate server for XDB. As your site expect visits 320k and that would definitely increase the xDB size over the period of time. Some times even you can expect suddenly xDB is not working or analytics reports not able to fetch the latest interaction data.

Answer (score 1):

We are recently upgraded Sitecore version from Sitecore 9 to 10. And now we are using SQL server instead of MongoDB for XDB. Also, we migrated contact information from Sitecore 9.1 MongoDB to Sitecore 10.1 SQL server.
The main problem we found is about the disk space. We migrated 10 million contacts and it took around 100GB space. Please note that we only migrate Contacts and contacts facets, not Interactions.

So, please keep salability in mind. If you are expecting a good amount of XDB data in near future, separate server is recommended.